# Github Action: Error: Input required and not supplied

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this pipeline which builds a release of my desktop app in windows and mac: https://github.com/ff14-advanced-market-search/AzerothAuctionAssassin/blob/main/.github/workflows/windows-exe-build.yml

The problem is that the mac build always fails to get the upload url with `Error: Input required and not supplied: upload_url`:

- https://github.com/ff14-advanced-market-search/AzerothAuctionAssassin/actions/runs/8022314656/job/21916504762
- https://github.com/ff14-advanced-market-search/AzerothAuctionAssassin/blob/main/.github/workflows/windows-exe-build.yml#L153

What is so strange is that this is only an issue on the projects original repo.  I forked this repo and it works perfectly!?!?

https://github.com/cohenaj194/AzerothAuctionAssassin/actions/runs/8022168254

What could be causing the issue in my main repo?

**update:** I have found the reason forks work is that this issue impacts organization repos only as it thinks the `output` variables contain secrets.

Comment: I found the source of the issue.  When run from an organization repo the output is masked and in the `complete job` step it says `Warning: Skip output 'upload_url' since it may contain secret.` This does not effect the personal forks.